# Recommendation system using meteor easysearch

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm finishing a project whose final challenge is that the system can recommend other websites based on positive vote to a site or comment on it.

The system uses a `keywords` field on which a search that uses `easysearch`, and upon which to base I want to make that recommendation system is based.

The algorithm is simple, when the user vote positive to the site the event is all your `keywords` and sends a `easysearch` that finds sites with at least one of the keywords, returns only one random site and returns the result in a nice modal message.

The template for the message is:

```
<template name="recommend_site">
        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="alertdialog" id="website_recommend">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h6 class="text-right">{{momentFormat createdOn}}</h6>
                        <p>
                            {{description}}
                        </p>
                        <a href="/site/{{_id}}">See more...</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <span class="badge alert-success">{{votes.Up}}</span>
                        {{#if currentUser}}
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                <button class="btn btn-default js-upvote">
                                    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-default js-downvote">
                                    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        {{/if}}
                        <span class="badge alert-danger">{{votes.Down}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

The event should make use of this search is:

```
Template.website_item.events({
        "click .js-upvote": function (event) {
            var website_id = this._id;
            var keywords = this.keywords;
            console.log("Up voting website with id " + website_id);

            Websites.update({_id: website_id},
                {$inc: {'votes.Up': 1}});

            WebsitesIndex.getComponentMethods().search(keywords);

            console.log(keywords);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

And example of the document website is :

```
Websites.insert({
            title:"Google",
            url:"http://www.google.com",
            description:"Popular search engine.",
            keywords: ['google', 'popular', 'search', 'engine'],
            votes:{
                Up: 0,
                Down: 0
            },
            createdOn:new Date()
        });
```

As I said before, sarch with [easysearch](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/) works great, but I can not locate that way to search keywords and taking send the result to the template. As you can see in the event I made an attempt to get the result following the documentation, but then there can not think what else I can do.

Someone can guide me ?

**Update**
I'm add some code in the event:

```
WebsitesIndex.getComponentMethods().search(keywords, { limit: 1 });
```

With `limit: 1`, i wait get one result for this search, but, i have a problem with this:

```
Exception in template helper: Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation
    at check (http://localhost:3000/packages/check.js?9c4972d3f4fe56cd455d3022e70b5195e642fc41:61:15)
    at MinimongoEngine.checkSearchParam (http://localhost:3000/packages/easysearch_core.js?a1c2859756f8a6aa5fec4727e1f529e581d0f124:386:7)
    at Index.search (http://localhost:3000/packages/easysearch_core.js?a1c2859756f8a6aa5fec4727e1f529e581d0f124:91:26)
    at Object.getCursor (http://localhost:3000/packages/easysearch_components.js?aa6c7b1263bc20dda4038492ac0d4fd3c5104ae8:331:26)
    at EachComponent.doc (http://localhost:3000/packages/easysearch_components.js?aa6c7b1263bc20dda4038492ac0d4fd3c5104ae8:956:63)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/peerlibrary_blaze-components.js?4eddb4e3f0f660190548347e680d109a51a7050f:1234:23
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:1650:16
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/peerlibrary_blaze-components.js?4eddb4e3f0f660190548347e680d109a51a7050f:1287:66
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:3671:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/peerlibrary_blaze-components.js?4eddb4e3f0f660190548347e680d109a51a7050f:1286:27
```

Well, i can see that problem is a helper problem, so, the global helper for the websiteIndex is:

```
Template.registerHelper('websiteIndex', () => WebsitesIndex);
```

But, i don't understand the problem yet.

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't capturing the html form and events directly in Javascript?

Comment: I don't understand you, sorry.

Comment: jQuery or pure Javascript can capture an easysearch request before or after it has occurred and process whatever you want.

Comment: OK, so, can you explain me these in an answer? Thanks.